# "Se los entrena": ¿se impersonal, pasiva refleja, o...?

Tags: gramática, oraciones-impersonales, oraciones-pasivas-reflejas

Estaba revisando unos ejercicios de gramática y encontré esta oración:

```
A medida que los niños van creciendo, se los entrena y se los pone a prueba para determinar si se han desarrollado los rasgos deseados.
```

Entiendo la frase bien, pero lo que no entiendo completamente son los grupos sintáticos

```
se los entrena
```

y

```
se los pone a prueba
```

¿Qué pasa aquí sintácticamente?  ¿Estamos ante la 'se impersonal', o la pasiva refleja, o otra cosa enteramente?  No creo que sea la pasiva refleja, porque a mi entender **no se pueden usar pronombres con ella**

```
Se vendieron los billetes
?? Se los vendieron <-- aquí tenemos otra construction, donde 'se' es un objeto indirecto (a mi entender)
```

Pues pienso que es la 'se impersonal'.  Pero ¿alguien puede explicarme lo que pasa aquí? Además, ¿son mis pensamientos sobre los pronombres y la pasiva refleja correctos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la oración:

> A medida que los niños van creciendo, se los entrena y se los pone a prueba para determinar si se han desarrollado los rasgos deseados.

el pronombre "se" es impersonal y, [según Manuel Seco](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Se%20le%20y%20se%20les%20en%20oraciones%20impersonales.htm), hay vacilación en la forma del pronombre clítico (*le/les* en España, *lo/la/los/las* en América) cuando se trata de verbos monotransitivos con objetos directos animados.

- Se **les** entrena (España)
- Se **los** entrena (América)
- Se **les** pone a prueba (España)
- Se **los** pone a prueba (América)

En cambio, el verbo "vender" puede ser ditransitivo (vender ALGO A ALGUIEN), y por lo tanto nos encontramos con las siguientes variantes:

- Se vendieron los billetes. (Pasiva con "se")
- Se los vendió. (Impersonal)
- Se los vendieron. (Esta oración tiene sujeto tácito en 3a personal del plural y "se" es marca de complemento indirecto, pudiendo referirse a *él/ella/ellos/ellas* = Ellos/Ellas vendieron los billetes a él/ella/ellos/ellos)